# added user-data script is not working after editing , but found working user-data while lauching a fresh EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, edit, user-data

My user-data script for installing Nginx was found to be working on a new launch of the EC2 instance. After launching the ec2 instance, I further added a PHP installation script by editing the user-data, which doesn't work for me.I am using ubuntu ubutu-20 lts image.
what may cause my problem?
(I have attached elastic IP to the instance )

Comment: Can you share your user_data?

Comment: my first data-
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install nano
mkdir /home/ubuntu/logs/
mkdir /home/ubuntu/logs/nginx
mkdir /home/ubuntu/public_html   
sudo apt-get install -y nginx
sudo systemctl enable nginx
sudo systemctl start nginx

Comment: after edit userdata-

Comment: Please update the question with  properly formated code blocks.

Comment: User data is executed once when you launch a new EC2. Are you launching another EC2 while changing the script?

Comment: answered here: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/execute-user-data-ec2/

Answer (score 0):

You can reflect your modified script by removing the below file and then reboot the instance:

```
/var/lib/cloud/instance/sem/config_scripts_user
```

command to remove:

```
rm /var/lib/cloud/instance/sem/config_scripts_user
```